# Firebase not sending notifications after account change/replacing firebase account

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement how to push notifications from firebase. I have added the dependencies and made a project in my firebase account and connected my app. It initially worked fine but I changed the firebase account that is associated with the app to another(2nd account) then I saw that I did not receive any notification so I deleted my project on the 2nd account and replaced my json files with the first one and reconnected to it again but I am not receiving any notification which was working previously. Here is my reference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-push-notification-in-android-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/
Here is my code for notification service

```
package com.crazy.pushnotifications

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage

class FirestoreNotification : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            // Since the notification is received directly from
            // FCM, the title and the body can be fetched
            // directly as below.
            showNotification(
                remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!,
                remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!
            )
        }

    }

    private fun getCustomDesign(title: String, message: String): RemoteViews {
        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(
            applicationContext.packageName,
            R.layout.layout_notification
        )
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(
            R.id.icon,
            R.drawable.ic_baseline_fingerprint_24
        );
        return remoteViews;
    }

    private fun showNotification(title: String, body: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val channelId = "notification_channel"
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        var builder = Notification.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_fingerprint_24)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            builder = builder.setContent(
                getCustomDesign(title, body)
            );
        } else {
            builder = builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_fingerprint_24)
        }

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        // Check if the Android Version is greater than Oreo
        // Check if the Android Version is greater than Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId, "CTQ",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())
        }
    }
}
```

and main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.crazy.pushnotifications">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pushnotifications"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".FirestoreNotification"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want to know if I made any mistake cause i didnot get any error but I didnot get any notification either.
NOTE: I have checked my gradle files and I am not missing any dependencies

Comment: Do you mean you changed the firebase auth user account logged in on the device, or you changed the firebase admin account you're sending notifications from?

Comment: There is no auth account here. As we get all the services like auth storage and messaging from a firebase account. This main account is replaced with another account. For example  an account associated with me@gmail.com is changed to you@gmail.com and all the steps are followed